# chaage value of Map scala based in key

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching

I have the following :

```
 val dynamoItem = rowAsMap.mapValues {
  v: Any => new AttributeValue().withS(v.toString)
}.asJava
```

I want to change the mapValues function and make it apply the appropriate function to value based on the Key

So if the Key is equal to `"AER"` I want it to do : `v: Any => new AttributeValue().withN(v.toString)`

and for other values of Key I wanted to make

```
 v: Any => new AttributeValue().withS(v.toString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to transform rowAsMap values (which are Map() values).

```
val dynamoItem = rowAsMap.map { item =>
  if (item._1 == "AER") 
     new AttributeValue().withN(item._2.toString)
  else 
     new AttributeValue().withS(item._2.toString)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the x._n notation to access tuple elements wherever possible. This is essentially the same answer provided above but I find this more readable.

```
val dynamoItem = rowAsMap.map { 
  case("AER", value) => "AER" -> new AttributeValue().withN(value.toString)
  case (key, value) => key -> new AttributeValue().withS(value.toString)
}
```

Note - I assume you are preserving keys and replacing values with `new  AttributeValue().withN(value.toString)` or `new AttributeValue().withS(value.toString)`